# Can I purchase manga online from the Kindle store?

Tags: merchandise, india

I live in Kolkata, India and everyone knows that looking for a manga store in this country is like searching for a needle in a haystack. So I was wondering if it was at all possible to purchase manga online from the Kindle eBook store.

Comment: have you tried to look on the kindle ebook store and seeing if purchase is possible?

Comment: Shows quite a lack of trying since my first google search turned up the link in my answer.

Comment: Being in India I was also struggling for manga but my friend managed to get one from amazon because as per price its great.

Answer (score 3):

You can buy manga On Amazon
http://www.amazon.in/Comics-Mangas-Books/b?ie=UTF8&node=1318104031

Also, Paperback Volumes are also available online and in select bookstores. Especially in Metros.

I for one buy many manga in the annual Comicon. Get promotional discounts and goodies.

Several Volumes are available as Kindle Edition. So I think thats what you were asking?